# Show full web address in Java EE application

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

Can anybody show me how to config the address path in a Java EE application? For example, it will be `www.abc.com/index.jsp` instead of displaying something like `www.abc.com/Welcome`.

Because I'm working on an old project and its developers have retired, I'm trying to map between the web addresses and the correct jsp files.

For example, Result.jsp is used to display the result. What I expect is that the web address should be www.abc.com/Result.jsp, instead of www.abc.com/Result (I don't know which jsp file is used to render the web page).

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. Please elaborate, e.g. with some examples and a rough description of your setup (don't throw lots of code at us). Otherwise that question is likely to be closed.

Comment: i dont know why they want to fix it while they can build a better and faster one

Answer (score 0):

Usually people try to do the opposite - hide the .jsp file from the user.

So instead of showing the page in the URL you'd better get more into the web framework that is used and see how it maps URLs to jsp pages. It is usually straightforward.

Comment: I know we should hide the jsp files, but i'm new to this project thus I need to know which jsp files are used behind the scence.

Comment: @Aptos You can know that using 'view source' by right-clicking on the browser page. Then see the name of notepad. I do that usually.

Comment: I wish I could do like that, their web pages has the same title and header :(